# What is the smallest possible SQL injection attack character sequence?

Tags: sql, code-injection

Simple, a SQL injection attack in as few characters as possible. Note, I'm not trying to prevent SQL injection attacks by limiting inputs to a certain size, but rather am genuinely curious how many characters is needed to execute even the simplest attack.

For posterity sake, let's say the smallest table name is 4 characters, e.g., "user". Please factor that in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1 Character is the smallest unit that you have control over. The question depends heavily on what you're doing. For instance, if you're dealing with an interface to delete your profile from a site, and you send '%' instead of your name:

```
"Delete from Users where name like '"+username+"'"
```

then setting your username to `%` will delete all the users.

Comment: What sane site would use `like`?

Comment: What sane site would allow SQL injection attacks?

Comment: None, but what sane site wouldn't sanitize their database inputs?

Comment: SQL injection is the natural path of a beginner developer.  Using `like` for this isn't.

Comment: I think you would be surprised at what people are capable of. Either way, given this contrived example, a single character would be capable of causing havoc.

Comment: Good example, it shows how dangerous SQL injection is. However, if you're using `' or 1=1 --`, it does not matter if you used `like` or not in your SQL command, it will always delete all users.

Answer (score 8):

When injecting into a string literal:

```
';drop database;--
```

Comment: I believe this is the answer I was seeking, as it is a more realistic use case. However, the other answer below, while maybe not realistic, is the shorter answer (and creative). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

how about this one:

```
' OR 1=1 --
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the query was generated like this

```
"Select * from user where userid = " + myVar 

1; delete from user;
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, if I trim my inline variable to have 13 chars max no dangerous sql injection is possible. In my sql 13 chars is enough to match any of my results with charindex. I cannot use parameterized stored procedure since my sql is dynamically generated in C# with complicated if else logic.